# File Upload always returns NULL in Safari Angular 8

Tags: angular, safari, angular-reactive-forms

I've been trying to get this working all day, works in Chrome, Opera, Firefox. Doesn't work in Safari.

Once a value has changed in the reactive form, in all the working browsers, the value changes and sets a file path to the image I am trying to upload.

This is what I see when it's working:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "feed_type": null,
  "title": "",
  "sub_title": "",
  "description": "",
  "text_content": "",
  "author_name": "",
  "author_avatar": "C:\\fakepath\\icon.png",<-- path is bound to form
  "video_url": "",
  "header_image": null,
  "featured_image": null,
  "twitter": "",
  "facebook": "",
  "instagram": "",
  "advertising_banner": null,
  "ad_link": ""
}
```

But in Safari:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "feed_type": null,
  "title": "",
  "sub_title": "",
  "description": "",
  "text_content": "",
  "author_name": "",
  "author_avatar": null,<-- path is not bound to form
  "video_url": "",
  "header_image": null,
  "featured_image": null,
  "twitter": "",
  "facebook": "",
  "instagram": "",
  "advertising_banner": null,
  "ad_link": ""
}
```

I have tried patchValues, setValues, after response on uploadImage to get the value for image upload to change in safari and it just doesn't work. This basically means, you can't send the form when using Safari, as all image values are just set to null and the validators will stop the form from being sent.

I've put in quite a bit of code to show how this works, but if you think there is more information needed, just ask as I'm banging my head against the wall. I've never known Safari to be this difficult.

**.html** - the image upload

```
<img class="placeholder" 
     *ngIf="selectedAvatarImage; else image_placeholder"
     [src]="imageUrl + selectedAvatarImage.url"><-- this is the preview, once it's succssfully been returned after upload
    <div class="file_wrapper">
        <input 
              type="file" 
              formControlName="author_avatar" 
              id="author_avatar"
              (change)="fileProgress($event)" 
              accept=".jpg,.svg,.png,.jpeg"
              required>
        <button class="update" (click)="uploadImage('author_avatar', selectedAvatarImage)"
              [style.background-color]="'#' + config.secondary_color.data.hex_code"
              [style.font-family]="config.header_font.data.font_family">Upload
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" 
    *ngIf="errorHandler('author_avatar', 'required') && submitted">
     An Author image is required
    </div>
```

**.ts** - the reactive form, the change event for upload, the upload image method

```
selectedAvatarImage: Image = null;
selectedFeaturedImage: Image = null;
selectedAdvertImage: Image = null;
selectedHeaderImage: Image = null;

ngOnInit() {
  this.articleCreate = this.formBuilder.group({
      status: 1,
      feed_type: [this.selectedFeed, [Validators.required]],
      title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20)]],
      sub_title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20)]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(80)]],
      text_content: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(300)]],
      author_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      author_avatar: [this.selectedAvatarImage, FileValidatorDirective.validate],
      video_url: [''],
      header_image: [this.selectedHeaderImage],
      featured_image:[this.selectedFeaturedImage, FileValidatorDirective.validate],
      twitter: [''],
      facebook: [''],
      instagram: [''],
      advertising_banner: [this.selectedAdvertImage, FileValidatorDirective.validate],
      ad_link: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  })
}

get form() {
  return this.articleCreate.controls;
}

fileProgress(fileInput: any) {
  this.fileData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
}

    uploadImage(key: string, imageFile) {
    this.startLoading();
    this.uploading = true;
    if (null) {
      return alert('Please choose an image first')
    }
    imageFile = this.fileData;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
    reader.onload = () => {
      let data = reader.result;
      this.configService.uploadImage({
        title: imageFile.name,
        name: imageFile.name,
        type: imageFile.type,
        size: imageFile.size, data
      }).subscribe(response => {
        this.stopLoading();
        imageFile = response.data;
        switch (key) {
          case 'author_avatar': this.selectedAvatarImage = response.data;
          console.log(this.selectedAvatarImage);
          this.articleCreate.controls['author_avatar'].setValue(this.selectedAvatarImage);
            break;
          case 'featured_image': this.selectedFeaturedImage = response.data;
            break;
          case 'advertising_banner': this.selectedAdvertImage = response.data;
            break;
          case 'header_image': this.selectedHeaderImage = response.data;
        }
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.uploading = false;
      }, 2000);
    }
  };
```

So, the image gets selected and uploaded, with no errors in the console. But when the rest of the form is complete e.g. text inputs select dropdowns etc, the image Validation fails even though, this.selectedAvatarImage, etc are in place.

I have tried to path the value on image upload, but Safari returns an invalid state error, I have tried to patch the value on change event, again the same. I can't seem to get those values to set before I send them.

On most of the approaches, Safari returns an error of invalid state or object is in an invalid state. The object coming down looks like this: This is the image class:

```
export class Image {
    id: number;
    url: string;
    name: string;
    title: string;
}
```

cannot work this one out...totally stumped.

Has anyone encountered this in the past?